# How am I supposed to decide how big to make buttons and other widgets

Tags: android

I am almost finished making my first app, and I've distributed the apk to some beta testers. The problem is, they all have different sized phones and some of them are saying the buttons are far too small, and some are saying they're fine. I have used concrete values in dp to specify the size of buttons. Am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: The first thing you should look for here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
And remember, dealing with android multiple screen sizes is alway a difficult problem, good luck!

Comment: Don't hardcode (use Concrete values) , instead use different sized images for different resolution devices(You can use Nine-Patch Generator) for this. Also, maximum use appropriate layout with wrap content/matchParent attributes for width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, do not hardcode values like that.

Assign dimensions according to the resolution of the device.

Or, you could find the width and height of the device and programatically assign LayoutParams to the Buttons, based on a certain ratio.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: Okay, I will try, but how do I know the size of the screens. This app is not just for me, I plan on making it available for free on the google playstore.

Comment: Updated my answer. And well, could you please explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, do not hardcode values.

Provide different layouts & different images for different screens & there shouldn't be any image related problems. You can use 9 patch generator.

If you are working with linear layouts, then using weightSum property will definitely save your times & layout related complexity.